# IE9 crash on jquery file change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

Here is my html code

```
 <div class="s-field" id="fileBox">
    <div style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
      <button style="width: 110px; height: 30px; position: relative; top: -5px; left: -5px;"
                                    title="Upload File">
                                    Upload File
       </button>
       <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="upload_input" CssClass="file" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                    Style="font-size: 50px; width: 120px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
                                    position: relative; top: -40px; left: -20px" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

my jquery

```
$('#upload_input').change(function (e) {

    var n = $(this).val();
   // alert(n); << if i comment out this alert it crashes the IE9

    var name = n.split('\\');
    var filename = name[name.length - 1];
    $('#fileBox').hide();
    $('#fileValue').html(filename);
    $('#fileValueDiv').show();

});
```

if i comment out alert statement it crashes the IE9. other browsers are fine.[image] 
i have no idea what the cause.

thanks for any help

Comment: Could you also post relevant parts of your HTML Code ?

Comment: if #fileValueDiv  is inside of #fileBox, that could be the problem

Comment: thanks @osdamv. no #fileValueDiv is not inside #fileBox. its next node.

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
window.alert = null ;
```

at the top of your javascript and uncomment the alert , it should work fine is . Please note that this is just a workaround

Comment: thanks satya. unfortunatly that didnt work. one thing i notice if i comment out this line of code " $('#fileBox').hide(); " then it work fine without an alert. i have added more html code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your code is in `$('document').ready(function() { ...thingymajiggy...});`

otherwise it could be something else in your installation. Try a fresh E9 instance on some other pc